# Java getClassLoader vs getSystemClassLoader, what are the differences?

Tags: java, classloader

We have a properties file, kafka.properties located under *src/main/resources* and the following two snippets of code.

**1:**
`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("kafka.properties");`

**2:** `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("kafka.properties");`

Both of these code snippets work fine on my local machine. However, whenever we deploy our application onto our cloud server only the **second** code snippet works.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the fact that on our server we are running a zipped .jar file, whereas when I run it locally IntelliJ compiles it in memory and uses the filesystem for lookup.

I'm curious what causes this and what the specific differences are between these two methods?

Comment: Did you read the JavaDocs for those methods ([one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()) and [two](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()))? What did you not understand?

Comment: *"I'm assuming it's something to do with ..."* - The difference is presumably that Kafka is creating a new classloader *dynamically* when it is run on the server.   You can get some clues by printing out what the two ways of getting a class loader give you ... in the two contexts.   But clearly, the 2nd way to do it is the way that works.